# paypal sdk integration for customer Future Payments

Tags: paypal

we have implementing paypal **Future Payment** functionality for customer who consent, so we deduct the amount from backend, in frontend we are using **connect with paypal** where we have got authorization_code but from backend we are using java rest api for convert authorization_code to get refresh_token , after that i m stuck like how we create payment of custome from refresh_token.